# The value set doesn't get displayed in the Medusa Gauge

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, gauge

I tried adding a Medusa Gauge to my JavaFX project that uses FXML.
I mapped the `fx:id` correctly in the scene builder and set a value to be displayed.

But unfortunately the value doesn't get displayed and only the default `0.00` is displayed.

Here is my code

Class that contains the main method - GaugeFX.java

```
public class GaugeFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Demo.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GaugeFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

FXML - Demo.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import eu.hansolo.medusa.Gauge?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gaugeDemoFX.DemoController">
   <children>
      <Gauge fx:id="gaugeExample" alert="true" alertMessage="Almost full" animated="true" areaTextVisible="true" layoutX="123.0" layoutY="113.0" lcdFont="ELEKTRA" skinType="SLIM" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXML Controller - DemoController.java

```
public class DemoController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Gauge gaugeExample;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        GaugeBuilder builder = GaugeBuilder.create();
        gaugeExample = builder.decimals(0).maxValue(10000).unit("Questions").build();
        gaugeExample.setValue(45);
    }    
}
```

I tried looking at the documentation. There the examples were done in hard coding. I noticed that the `Gauge`'s value was set before showing the stage.

> https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-992746

But according to my knowledge i have done the same even if i used FXML to make the project.

Can someone please tell me where i went wrong that the value i set doesn't get displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting value of the field containing the `Gauge` created in the fxml with a new one in the `initialize` method. The new one is never added to the scene; you only see the old unmodified one.

If `Gauge` works the same way JavaFX standard `Control`s work, you only need to use setters instead of using the builder:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    gaugeExample.setDecimals(0);
    gaugeExample.setMaxValue(10000);
    gaugeExample.setUnit("Questions");
    gaugeExample.setValue(45);
}
```

Furthermore it should also be possible to assign the properties from the fxml file:

```xml
<Gauge fx:id="gaugeExample"
       alert="true"
       alertMessage="Almost full"
       animated="true"
       areaTextVisible="true"
       layoutX="123.0"
       layoutY="113.0"
       lcdFont="ELEKTRA"
       skinType="SLIM"
       decimals="0"
       maxValue="10000"
       unit="Questions"
       value="45" />
```

Comment: i had a hard time understanding what to do because the doc i referred had examples done in hard coding.. thanks for the help